# Facebook style- Adding captions to photos

Tags: php, arrays, upload, photo

Im trying to figure out the best way to add captions to a set of photos. This is the process:

1. User uploads photos (Ex: 10)
2. After upload is successful (save in a folder labeled by their username), the page refreshes and the photos appear in a list with a "caption" input next to it.
3. Users type in their captions and click "Submit"
4. The photo captions are saved

What Im having a hard time figuring out is how do I get the photo names and captions into an array? The image names will already be set, and I'll already have an array from the photo upload. How do I add the captions to each photo in the array?

Thank you for your help! Any suggestions on doing it different are welcome'd!

Brandon

Comment: I guess the input elements have to somehow be linked to their respective images via some identifier.  The ID can be passed to your PHP script on form submission so you know for which photo to add the caption.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

1. Have index.html with the  file upload
2. Goes to upload.php: Uploads the file and saves them into the user's folder (ex: brandon/photos/)
3. After upload completes, "echo" photos using "foreach" with a input "text" box. Each text box has the "name" of "captions[]" that builds an array of captions
4. On submission, goes to "addcaptions.php": Combines the files array and the captions array
5. addcaptions.php then adds, using "foreach", the photo filenames, the corresponding caption, and the username that corresponds to the photo to a MySql database using "mysqli"

And it works perfectly! All photos and captions are combined and ready to be used!

Thank you everyone for taking a look at this problem!